# Improved first Tic-Tac-Toe + Minimax AI

Tags: c++, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, ai

Posted my first attempt at Tic-Tac-Toe a second ago [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220597/first-program-tic-tac-toe). Got a lot of great and helpful responses. The main things I took away from these responses was to use spell check, and to keep things simple. Wanted to give it a second go before moving on to something a bit bigger.

Learned about the Minimax algorithm from [this](https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/minimax) article. It doesn't work *exactly* like I'd hope but I can't tell if it's just the pitfalls of the algorithm or my code.

I'm grateful for any critique or pointers.

**tictactoe.h**

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE
#define TICTACTOE
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum class BoardValue{ none, o, x};

class Board
{
public:
    Board() = default;
    Board(const Board& board): o_bits(board.o_bits), x_bits(board.x_bits) {};
    BoardValue at(int index) const;
    bool check_tie() const;
    bool check_win(bool) const;
    bool place(int, bool);
    std::vector<int> possible_moves() const;
private:
    std::bitset<9> o_bits{};
    std::bitset<9> x_bits{};
    std::bitset<9> filled_bits() const{ return o_bits | x_bits; }
};

class AI
{
public:
    AI(bool o) : is_o(o) {};
    int best_move(const Board&);
private:
    int minimax(const Board&, int, bool);

    int choice{};
    bool is_o; //is the ai playing as 'O'
};
#endif
```

**tictactoe.cpp**

```
#include "tictactoe.h"
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

BoardValue Board::at(int index) const{
    if(index < 0 || 8 < index) throw std::out_of_range{ "Index out of Board range" };
    if(filled_bits().test(index) == true)
    {
        return (o_bits.test(index) ? BoardValue::o : BoardValue::x);
    }
    else return BoardValue::none;
}

bool Board::check_tie() const
{
    std::bitset<9> full_board{ "111111111" };
    if( full_board == (filled_bits() & full_board) ) return true;
    return false;
}

bool Board::check_win(bool o) const
{
    const std::bitset<9>& bits = o ? o_bits : x_bits; //bits to be checked

    //diagonals
    if(bits.test(4) != false) //if middle is not taken no diagonals will pass
    {
        std::bitset<9> forward_diagonal{ "100010001" }; //bits of '\'
        std::bitset<9> backward_diagonal{ "001010100" }; //bits of '/'
        if(forward_diagonal == (bits & forward_diagonal)) return true;
        if(backward_diagonal == (bits & backward_diagonal)) return true;
    }

    //columns and rows
    std::bitset<9> col_check{ "001001001" }; //bits of the first column/row
    std::bitset<9> row_check{ "000000111" };
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) // loop for all 3 columns and rows
    {
        if(col_check == (bits & col_check)) return true;
        if(row_check == (bits & row_check)) return true;
        col_check = col_check << 1; //move over a column/row over
        row_check = row_check << 3;
    }

    return false;
}

//returns false if index is occupied
bool Board::place(int index, bool o)
{
    if(at(index) != BoardValue::none) return false;

    std::bitset<9>& bits = o ? o_bits : x_bits; //bits to be changed
    bits.set(index);
    return true;
}

//returns indexes of free spaces
//all returned indexes will return true when used in place(int,bool)
std::vector<int> Board::possible_moves() const
{
    const std::bitset<9> bits = filled_bits();
    std::vector<int> moves{};
    //loop through each bit and add the index of the ones that are 0 to possible_moves
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        if( bits.test(i) == false)
        {
            moves.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return moves;
}

int AI::best_move(const Board& board)
{
    minimax(board, 0, true);
    return choice;
}

int AI::minimax(const Board& position, int depth, bool maxPlayer)
{
    //check position game state and return score if game is lost, won, or tied
    if(position.check_win(!is_o)) //AI loses
    {
        return depth - 10;
    }
    else if(position.check_win(is_o)) //AI wins
    {
        return 10 - depth;
    }
    else if(position.check_tie())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //do minimax calculation
    if(maxPlayer)
    {
        int max_move{};
        int max_move_score{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min()};
        for(int move : position.possible_moves())
        {
            Board possible_position{ position };
            possible_position.place(move, is_o);
            int score = minimax(possible_position, ++depth, false);
            if ( score > max_move_score )
            {
                max_move = move;
                max_move_score = score;
            }
        }

        choice = max_move;//last call to this will be at first call to minimax() from best_move()
        return max_move_score; //return max score
    }
    else
    {
        int min_move{};
        int min_move_score{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
        for(int move : position.possible_moves())
        {
            Board possible_position{ position };
            possible_position.place(move, !is_o);
            int score = minimax(possible_position, ++depth, true);
            if ( score < min_move_score )
            {
                min_move = move;
                min_move_score = score;
            }
        }

        return min_move_score; //return max score
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "tictactoe.h"
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int ask_player_input()
{
    bool retry{ false };
    int index{};

    std::cout << "It's your turn. Where do you want to go(e.g. A1 B3 C2)? ";
    do{
        if(retry)
        {
            std::cout << "No, no, no! Input a letter followed by a number: ";
        }
        retry = false; //reset retry

        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input.size() < 2)
        {
            retry = true;
            continue;
        }

        //letter input
        int col_input{};
        switch(input.at(0))
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                col_input = 0;
                break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                col_input = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                col_input = 2;
                break;
            default:
                retry = true;
                continue;
        }

        //number input
        int row_input = input.at(1) - '0'; //converts char '2' to int 2
        if(--row_input < 0 || 3 < row_input)
        {
            retry = true;
            continue;
        }

        index = col_input * 3 + row_input;
    } while( retry );
    return index;
}

bool ask_turn() //ask who will go first if return true O goes first
{
    bool turn{};
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Who do you want to be?(X or O)? ";
    for(bool valid_input{false}; !valid_input;)
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        switch(input.front()) //input cannot be null at this point
        {
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                valid_input = true;
                turn = false;
                break;
            case '0':
            case 'o':
            case 'O':
                valid_input = true;
                turn = true;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Invalid input! Try X or O :";
        }
    }
    return turn;
}

std::ostream& print_board(std::ostream& os,const Board& board)
{
    os << " |A|B|C\n";
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
    {
        os << std::string( 8, '-') << '\n';
        os << row + 1 << '|';
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
        {
            char follow_char{ col == 2 ? '\n' : '|' };
            char place_char{};

            //determine character to print for this board place on the board
            BoardValue place_value  = board.at(col * 3 + row);
            if(place_value == BoardValue::none) place_char = ' ';
            else place_char = place_value == BoardValue::o ? 'O' : 'X';

            os << place_char << follow_char;
        }
    }
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Board& board)
{
    return print_board(os, board);
}

int main(){
    std::default_random_engine e{ static_cast<long unsigned int>(time(NULL)) };
    bool turn{ e() % 2 };
    bool player_turn{ ask_turn() };
    Board board{};
    AI ai{ !player_turn };

    if(turn != player_turn)//player first, turns will be flipped at start of game loop
    {
        std::cout << "You go first!\n" << board;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Computer gets to go first this time. Good luck!\n";
    }

    while(board.check_win(turn) == false && board.check_tie() == false)
    {
        turn = !turn;
        if(turn == player_turn)
        {
            bool input_valid{false};
            while(input_valid == false)
            {
                int input;
                input = ask_player_input();
                input_valid = board.place(input, turn);
                if( input_valid == false )
                    std::cout << "That place is take! Try again...\n";
            }
        }
        else //AI turn
        {
            int best_move = ai.best_move(board);
            board.place( best_move, turn);

            std::cout << board;
            //print AI turn
            std::array<char,3> col_chars = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
            char col_input = col_chars.at( best_move % 3 );
            int row_input = ((best_move + 1) / 3) + 1;

            std::cout << "Computer picks " << col_input << row_input << '\n';
        }
    }
    std::cout << board;
    if(board.check_tie())
    {
        std::cout << "Looks like its a tie...\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << (turn == player_turn ? "You won!" : "The computer wins..." )  << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not time to check all the program, but I still spotted something I want to share:

This:

```
switch (input.front()) //input cannot be null at this point
{
case 'x':
case 'X':
    valid_input = true;
    turn = false;
    break;
case '0':
case 'o':
case 'O':
    valid_input = true;
    turn = true;
    break;
default:
    std::cout << "Invalid input! Try X or O :";
}
```

If you turn your compiler warnings on a high level you probably get complaints that you left out some `break`-statements. If you use C++17 you should state your intention with [[[fallthrough]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough):

```
switch (input.front()) //input cannot be null at this point
{
case 'x':
    [[fallthrough]]
case 'X':
    valid_input = true;
    turn = false;
    break;
case '0':
    [[fallthrough]]
case 'o':
    [[fallthrough]]
case 'O':
    valid_input = true;
    turn = true;
    break;
default:
    std::cout << "Invalid input! Try X or O :";
}
```